# Differentiate between admin and normal User for Firebase (Xcode ios app)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently developing an IOS app and what i want to do is differentiate between admin users and normal users when logging into the app because at the moment a normal user can log in and get access to the admin options. I'm using Firebase as my database but there's no option to differentiate. Any help would be much appreciated. 
Here's my code for login

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text{

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) {(user, error) in

            if let firebaseError = error{
                print (firebaseError.localizedDescription)
                self.showAlert("Invalid Email or Password")

                return
            }
            self.presentLoggedInScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

I accept if anyone downvotes this post but please comment below why you doing so. Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad because you're essentially asking for someone to design the security model for your app without understanding what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use other things to implement some role based authentication, you can check examples here to give you some ideas: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Comment: No swift option available on the link you provided

Comment: Well, the first examples are for server side, for a client like a swift app, check the entry "Access custom claims in the client": [client examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client)

Comment: This is the correct answer. You set the custom claims server side, you detect them from client in the examples listed. There is a swift example there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add rules to your Firebase database:

Got to your database on your Firebase console then click on your Rule Tab on you right side and add one of the following examples adapted to your code.

For example, here everyone has access to your /foo/ path but no one can write to it:

```
service cloud.firestore{
    "rules": {
        "foo": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": false
        }
    }
}
```

So, if you want a certain autoriztion to some path for determinated users you can do it as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
                "foo": {
                ".read": true,
                ".write": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can do it with a parameter to restrict foo access to a specific uid:

```
"foo":{
  ".read": "auth.uid != null &&
            query.orderByChild == 'owner' && query.equalTo == auth.uid"
}
```